# Send Customised Text in textFlow from server to client

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

Here is the scenario. I’m a newbie dealing with JavaFX. I made an interface for messenger and implemented successfully with a server-client interaction. My Interface is like this -> TextFlow and one textField and a button. I used a text flow as a history panel where messages are shown. I used text flow because I wanted to assign the color to that text. 
Here is the problem. When I selected color, say blue,for text and typed the message and hit the send button, Message got sent to the client and also got stored in server history panel with the selected color, say blue. But on the client side, the message received is in black color, not blue.
If anybody understood the scenario, please help me with your advice. 
How can I store the text flow messages which are customized and to send that customized text to clients side  unchanged?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you do that in the client side ?
here's a little trick :

```
private Text returnedtxt;
private Text msgPrefix(String txt){

     if(txt.startsWith("@msg")){

        //Substract String
        //returnedtxt = new Text (substracted);
        //Apply font 
        //apply fill

     }else if (txt.startsWith("@log")){

        //Substract String
        //returnedtxt = new Text (substracted);
        //Apply font 
        //apply fill

     }else if (txt.startsWith("@exp")){

        //Substract String
        //returnedtxt = new Text (substracted);
        //Apply font 
        //apply fill

     }

   return returnedtxt;

}
```

Comment: Yep bro.. may be ur idea works.. nope it works.. but not in my case.. ive got maore than text to sned to client.. so pleave give an advice to sned customised text. That would be of great help